# How to display input always next to each other without wrap?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid of 5x3 filled with input fields and div's.

```css
.container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "empty temparatur blutdruck puls saettigung"
    "vor i-temparatur i-blutdruck i-puls i-saettigung"
    "bei i-temparatur-2 i-blutdruck-2 i-puls-2 i-saettigung-2";
}

.empty { grid-area: empty; }

.temparatur { grid-area: temparatur; }

.blutdruck { grid-area: blutdruck; }

.puls { grid-area: puls; }

.saettigung { grid-area: saettigung; }

.vor { grid-area: vor; }

.i-blutdruck { grid-area: i-blutdruck; }

.i-temparatur { grid-area: i-temparatur; }

.i-puls { grid-area: i-puls; }

.i-saettigung { grid-area: i-saettigung; }

.bei { grid-area: bei; }

.i-temparatur-2 { grid-area: i-temparatur-2; }

.i-blutdruck-2 { grid-area: i-blutdruck-2; }

.i-puls-2 { grid-area: i-puls-2; }

.i-saettigung-2 { grid-area: i-saettigung-2; }

.i-blutdruck-1 { white-space: nowrap; }

.i-blutdruck-2 { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="temparatur">Temparatur</div>
  <div class="blutdruck">Blutdruck</div>
  <div class="puls">Puls</div>
  <div class="saettigung">02-Sättigung</div>
  <div class="vor">vor</div>
  <input class="i-temparatur" type="text"/>
  <div class="i-blutdruck" type="text">
    <input class="i-blutdruck-1" type="text"/>
    <span>/</span>
    <input class="i-blutdruck-2" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <input class="i-puls" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-saettigung" type="text"/>
  <div class="bei">bei</div>
  <input class="i-temparatur-2" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-blutdruck-2" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-puls-2" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-saettigung-2" type="text"/>
</div>
```

In Column two i have two input fields inside the same div. When minimizing the browser width, the second input falls below the first:
[image]

The inputs inside the div always should be on the same line and in between the two inputs should be the "slash". There should be no break or wrap.

I tried it with `white-space: nowrap;` and with `display: inline-block`, but both didn't work for me.

How can i keep the two inputs inside the div "i-blutdruck" on the same line with the span "slash" in between?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using `display: flex;` in the wrapper div:

```css
.container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "empty temparatur blutdruck puls saettigung"
    "vor i-temparatur i-blutdruck i-puls i-saettigung"
    "bei i-temparatur-2 i-blutdruck-2 i-puls-2 i-saettigung-2";
}

.empty { grid-area: empty; }

.temparatur { grid-area: temparatur; }

.blutdruck { grid-area: blutdruck; }

.puls { grid-area: puls; }

.saettigung { grid-area: saettigung; }

.vor { grid-area: vor; }

.i-blutdruck { grid-area: i-blutdruck; display: flex;}

.i-temparatur { grid-area: i-temparatur; }

.i-puls { grid-area: i-puls; }

.i-saettigung { grid-area: i-saettigung; }

.bei { grid-area: bei; }

.i-temparatur-2 { grid-area: i-temparatur-2; }

.i-blutdruck-2 { grid-area: i-blutdruck-2; }

.i-puls-2 { grid-area: i-puls-2; }

.i-saettigung-2 { grid-area: i-saettigung-2; }

.i-blutdruck-1 { white-space: nowrap; }

.i-blutdruck-2 { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="temparatur">Temparatur</div>
  <div class="blutdruck">Blutdruck</div>
  <div class="puls">Puls</div>
  <div class="saettigung">02-Sättigung</div>
  <div class="vor">vor</div>
  <input class="i-temparatur" type="text"/>
  <div class="i-blutdruck" type="text">
    <input class="i-blutdruck-1" type="text"/>
    <span>/</span>
    <input class="i-blutdruck-2" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <input class="i-puls" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-saettigung" type="text"/>
  <div class="bei">bei</div>
  <input class="i-temparatur-2" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-blutdruck-2" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-puls-2" type="text"/>
  <input class="i-saettigung-2" type="text"/>
</div>
```